# How to change group_by key and group_by value in Activercord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to group the result of this association and I cannot obtain the result I need. I need to group the results changing the key and also the values...

```
=> [#<ProductDB::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2e34a3cc8
  id: 356575368,
  raw_value: "6.5",
  presentional_value: "16,5 cm (6.5\")",
  product_id: 10091,
  feature_id: 944,
  search_type: nil,
  searchable: true,
  order: 10100500,
  product_features_group_id: nil,
  category_feature_id: 51494,
  category_feature_group_id: 6883>,
 #<ProductDB::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2e34a2cb0
  id: 356640278,
  raw_value: "6.67",
  presentional_value: "16,9 cm (6.67\")",
  product_id: 10093,
  feature_id: 944,
  search_type: nil,
  searchable: true,
  order: 10100500,
  product_features_group_id: nil,
  category_feature_id: 51494,
  category_feature_group_id: 6883>,
 #<ProductDB::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2e34a1a68
  id: 356578363,
  raw_value: "6.5",
  presentional_value: "16,5 cm (6.5\")",
  product_id: 10092,
  feature_id: 944,
  search_type: nil,
  searchable: true,
  order: 10100500,
  product_features_group_id: nil,
  category_feature_id: 51494,
  category_feature_group_id: 6883>
```

This is the result of this query

```
products_features.where(product_id: params["products"].map(&:to_i))
```

I have to group these records by feature_id but I need to change the key and the value of the grouped results.

If I use

```
products_features.where(product_id: params["products"].map(&:to_i)).group_by(&:feature_id)
```

The result is

```
 {944=>
  [#<DdayProducts::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2ca56e1f8
    id: 356575368,
    raw_value: "6.5",
    presentional_value: "16,5 cm (6.5\")",
    product_id: 10091,
    feature_id: 944,
    search_type: nil,
    searchable: true,
    order: 10100500,
    product_features_group_id: nil,
    category_feature_id: 51494,
    category_feature_group_id: 6883>,
   #<DdayProducts::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2ca56e090
    id: 356640278,
    raw_value: "6.67",
    presentional_value: "16,9 cm (6.67\")",
    product_id: 10093,
    feature_id: 944,
    search_type: nil,
    searchable: true,
    order: 10100500,
    product_features_group_id: nil,
    category_feature_id: 51494,
    category_feature_group_id: 6883>,
   #<DdayProducts::ProductFeature:0x00007fa2ca56df28
    id: 356578363,
    raw_value: "6.5",
    presentional_value: "16,5 cm (6.5\")",
    product_id: 10092,
    feature_id: 944,
    search_type: nil,
    searchable: true,
    order: 10100500,
    product_features_group_id: nil,
    category_feature_id: 51494,
    category_feature_group_id: 6883>]
```

But instead of the ID `944` I need the feature name (`feature.name` association) as key and I need also to map the grouped results extracting for each item of the group the product_id as key.

Se the result should be:

The result is

```
 {"Display Size"=>
  [ 10091: {...},
    10093: {...},
    10092: {...}
  ]
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method. Hashing nested by default makes our job easier. Default object for `each_with_object` creates the following hash structure for us:

```
default_object = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] } }

{ 
  key_foo =>
    { 
      key1 => [],
      key2 => [],
      key3 => [],
      ...
    },
  key_boo =>
    {
      key1 => [],
      key2 => [],
      ...
    },
  ...
}
default_object[:key_foo]
# => {}
default_object[:key_foo][:key1]
# => []
default_object[:key_bla][:key134]
# => []
```

Now you can create the group as you like:

```
pfs = products_features.where(product_id: params["products"].map(&:to_i))
default_object = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] } }
result = pfs.each_with_object(default_object) do |product_feature, obj|
  obj[product_feature.feature.name][product_feature.product_id] << product_feature
end

print result
# =>
#   {
#     "Display Size" =>
#       {
#         10091 => [...],
#         10093 => [...],
#         10092 => [...]
#       },
#     ...
#   }
```